# How to ignore strings that start with certain pattern using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Accept and return @something but reject first@last.

```
r'@([A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*[A-Z0-9])
```

The above regexp will accept @something (starts with letter, ends with letter or number, may have underscore in middle, atleast 2 characters long) and returns the part after the `@` symbol.

I do not want to return strings which contain some letters or number `A-Z0-9` before the `@` symbol.

Spaces, new lines, special characters, etc before `@` is allowed.

CODE:

```
re.findall(r'@([A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*[A-Z0-9])', text, re.I)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
re.findall(r'(?<![A-Z0-9])@([A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*[A-Z0-9])', text, re.I)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/eEJ5zx/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z0-9]                 any character of: 'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @                        '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z0-9_]*               any character of: 'A' to 'Z', '0' to
                             '9', '_' (0 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z0-9]                 any character of: 'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\B@([A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*[A-Z0-9])
```

The pattern matches:

- `\B` Assert a position where a word boundary does not match
- `@` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*[A-Z0-9]`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vads1l/1)

```
import re

text = "Accept and return @something but reject first@last."
print(re.findall(r'\B@([A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*[A-Z0-9])', text, re.I))
```

Output

```
['something']
```